# ReSharper stopped tracking Visual Studio code analysis after VS was updated to 17.5

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, code-analysis

I have some C# solutions which use StyleCop analyser and Ruleset file with some custom rules. Then I have updated Visual Studio from 17.4 to 17.5.1 and ReSharper stopped tracking violations of rules.

When ReSharper is enabled it shows only its own warnings:

[image]

Without ReSharper it works fine:

[image]

It's definitely not an issue with cache. Could you advise me how to fix this without rolling back to version 17.4, please?

Comment: Are you calling the LogSomething() method from somewhere - I get the ReSharper fix for making it static - it is a ReSharper fix, nothing to do with StyleCop. I am using VS17.5.1, ReSharper 2022.3.2, .NET 7 (and StyleCop.Analyzers 1.1.118 nuget package)

Comment: @PiersMyers, I'm using VS17.5.1, ReSharper 2022.3.2, .NET 6 and StyleCop.Analyzers 1.2.0-beta.435. The method is not used anywhere - this is just a sample code for a demo. ReSharper is silent and does not respond to such things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing R# a 2023.1 EAP build, I believe this issue should be fixed there.

Comment: Odd that ReSharper 2022.3.2 offered the fix to me though. Hopefully the RC version of 2023.1 will be out soon :)